# All remote connections failing in startup script on EC2 Windows instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm using an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I have a scheduled task triggered on start up that pulls from a git repo and an s3 bucket.

When I RDP in and run the task myself everything works just lovely but when I restart the instance and allow the `onstart` trigger to kick off the script it always hangs on the first attempt to fetch a remote resource. Its the same if its an s3 bucket or a git repo.

Here is the output for the read s3 bucket:

```
Read-S3Object : Access Denied
At C:\Scripts\bootstrap.ps1:8 char:1
+ Read-S3Object -BucketName my-bucket -Key myScript.ps1 -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...dS3ObjectCmdlet:ReadS3ObjectCmdlet) [Read-S3Object] 
   , InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.ReadS3ObjectCmdlet
```

Here is the output when it fails on the git clone:

```
git : Cloning into 'myWork.myApp'...
At C:\Scripts\bootstrap.ps1:12 char:1
+ git clone -v git@bitbucket.org:myTeam/myWork.myApp.git
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Cloning into 'a....initialize'...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Host key verification failed.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I cant for the life of me work out why this is failing. Should I be using the instances `UserData` for my script and if that is the case why exactly?

Comment: Are the users same when you RDP in and on startup? It looks to me 2 different users. Host key verification error message corroborates it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. So I ran Start Transcript to capture some output and that showed the correct user in the header... The startup script is being triggered as a scheduled task and that is set up to run as the correct user... puzzled.

Comment: Same issue here, did you figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Work it out? No. Got a work around going for our use case but it might not apply....

Comment: If you are using SSH key, for example, in case of GIT, then you will need to add the host(Bitbucket, GitHub etc) to the list of known hosts. You need to run this in bash: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`(replace with Github.com it it applies in your case). More info here: https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts. Secondly, create the task using schtasks.exe and provide the username & password of an administrator: https://superuser.com/questions/1031539/create-schedule-task-from-xml-file-by-batch-file